# Ant FTP task - cannot create type

Tags: ant

Could someone help me with Ant? I want to deploy some files through FTP but i still can't due to error:

```
Could not create type ftp due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClientConfig
```

In ant lib directory I have:

- lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root ant-bootstrap.jar -> ../../java/ant-bootstrap.jar
- lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root ant-commons-net.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-commons-net.jar
- lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root ant.jar -> ../../java/ant.jar
- lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root ant-launcher.jar -> ../../java/ant-launcher.jar
- lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root commons-net.jar -> /usr/share/java/commons-net.jar

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you are using ant 1.8.

You need `apache-commons-net-2.0.jar` and  `jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar` in the lib folder as listed in this [blogpost](http://projectfed.blogspot.com/2010/11/installing-ftp-task-on-ant-18x-on.html) and  [in the docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar)(Although the doc says 1.4 should be enough)

Comment: I'm using Ant 1.8.3. I have downloaded files: commons-net 2.0 and oro-2.0.8, moved them to lib directory but result is still the same :-(

Comment: @JosefZamrzla did you remove the old commons-net.jar?

Comment: Now I really don't know. I have re-installed ant (again :-/), replace nested JAR-files and now it runs ok... Maybe the was a mistake that ANT_HOME wasn't defined, but I'm not sure... Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse:

```
Window > Preferences > Ant > Runtime > Classpath Tab > Ant Home Entries (Default) > Add External jars

   1.commons-net-2.0.jar

   2.oro-2.0.8.jar
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: This also worked for me.  Placing the jar files in %ant_home%/lib did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Debian Linux distribution or Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi, you can simply solve this problem by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libcommons-net-java
```